# How to make this publisher extension generic

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have the following extension on a `Publisher` which allows me to paginate a URL request. I originally used this in a specific use case, where the `Output` of the publisher was of type `CustomType`.

```
extension Publisher where Output == CustomType,
                          Failure == Error {
  func paginate(pageIdPublisher: CurrentValueSubject<String?, Never>) -> AnyPublisher<[User], Never> {
    return self
      .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { response in
        if let maxId = response.pageId {
          pageIdPublisher.send(maxId)
        } else {
          pageIdPublisher.send(completion: .finished)
        }
      })
      .reduce([]) { allUsers, response in
        return response.users + allUsers
      }
      .catch { error in
        Just([])
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}

struct CustomType: Codable {
  let users: [User]
  let pageId: String?
}
```

This is called like this:

```
func loadItem() async throws -> [String] {
  let pageIdPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<String?, Never>(nil)

  return try await pageIdPublisher
    .flatMap { pageId in
      urlSession
        .publisher(
          for: .item(pageId: pageId),
          receiveOn: queue
        )
    }
    .paginate(pageIdPublisher: pageIdPublisher) // <- This part
    .singleOutput()
}
```

However, I now want to make it generic so that it can be used on any `Output` type, so long as it has a `pageId` and some kind of array.

I tried using a protocol `Pageable` like this:

```
protocol Pageable {
  associatedtype T

  var pageId: String? {get}
  var items: [T] {get}
}
```

But I can't use that with the extension because `Output` can't have be used with a protocol that contains an `associatedType`.

Is this possible?

Comment: You would be kinder to your potential helpers if you provided enough code to allow your example code to _compile_.

Comment: Added a bit more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you constrained the `Output` type with `:` to your `Pageable` protocol, and used `Output.T` for the returned publisher's output type, the `paginate` method should compile:

```
extension Publisher where Output: Pageable,
                          Failure == Error {
  func paginate(pageIdPublisher: CurrentValueSubject<String?, Never>) -> AnyPublisher<[Output.T], Never> {
   return self
     .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { response in
       if let maxId = response.pageId {
         pageIdPublisher.send(maxId)
       } else {
         pageIdPublisher.send(completion: .finished)
       }
     })
     .reduce([]) { allItems, response in
       return response.items + allItems
     }
     .catch { error in
       Just([])
     }
     .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

Another idea of making this more generic would be to constrain `Output` to be an `Identifiable` type, where `ID` is an optional, and provide an extra closure argument to specify the mapping from `Output` to the array:

```
extension Publisher where Output: Identifiable,
                          Failure == Error {
    func paginate<T, ID>(
        pageIdPublisher: CurrentValueSubject<Output.ID?, Never>,
        items: @escaping (Output) -> [T]
    )
        -> AnyPublisher<[T], Never>
        where Self.Output.ID == ID?
    {
        ...

    }
}
```

You would use `response.id` instead of `response.pageId`, and `items(response)` instead of `response.items` in the implementation. At the callsite, you would pass in `\.users` for the closure argument, for example.

Comment: The update you made to this was perfect! That solved another problem that I didn't even mention in the question. You're a rockstar, thank you so much.